# Evaluate an integral quickly

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Evaluate the integral $$\int \sqrt{x} \ln(1+x)dx $$

so we should start with the substitution: $t=\sqrt{x}$

$$ \int t\ln(1+t)dt2t = 2\int t^2\ln(1+t)dt $$

From here, it seems reasonable to integrate by parts;

$$\frac{t^3}{3}\ln(1+t) - \frac{1}{3} \int \frac{t^3}{1+t} dt$$

So basically we left with evaluating $\int \frac{t^3}{1+t}dt$

And I guess the trick here is to do the following algebraic trick:

$$\int \frac{t^3}{1+t}dt = \int \frac{t^3 + t^2 - t^2}{1+t} dt = \int \frac{t^2(t+1) - t^2}{1+t} dt = \int t^2 - \int \frac{t^2}{1+t}$$

And that's leaves us with a similar problem (And I could go fourth of course)

So although it wasn't that tedious.. Is there a quicker way?

Comment: $\ln(1+x)=\ln(1+t^2)$ if $t=\sqrt{x}$. After you correct that, try the same idea again.

Comment: By the way, the trick of adding and subtracting $t^2$ have the same purpose and is done better by applying long division to $t^3$ divided by $t+1$. You get $p(x)+\frac{c}{1+x}$ where $p(x)$ is the quotient (a polynomial) and $c$ is the remainder (a constant in this case).

Comment: With the $t^3/(1+t)$, you can make the substitution $u = 1+t$.  This gives you an integrand of $(u-1)^3/u$.  You can expand out the numerator to get an integral that's relatively easy to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Using the antiderivative

$$\int\sqrt{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac23x^{3/2}+\color{grey}{constant}$$

and the derivative

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln{(1+x)}=\frac{1}{1+x},$$

we can integrate by parts to find,

$$\int\sqrt{x}\,\ln{\left(1+x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac23x^{3/2}\,\ln{\left(1+x\right)}-\int\frac{\frac23x^{3/2}}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Integrating by parts first like this is probably the quicker route.